# Shanks's square form factorization implementation

Tags: c, factors, factorization

Recently I have been studying about Shanks's square form factorization from this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanks%27s_square_forms_factorization)
An implementation in C is provided on that page. I was testing that function and noticed that the function is failing to find a factor of 27.

This is the given C function:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#define nelems(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

const int multiplier[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 3*5, 3*7, 3*11, 5*7, 5*11, 7*11, 3*5*7, 3*5*11, 3*7*11, 5*7*11, 3*5*7*11};

uint64_t SQUFOF( uint64_t N )
{
    uint64_t D, Po, P, Pprev, Q, Qprev, q, b, r, s;
    uint32_t L, B, i;
    s = (uint64_t)(sqrtl(N)+0.5);
    if (s*s == N) return s;
    for (int k = 0; k < nelems(multiplier) && N <= UINT64_MAX/multiplier[k]; k++) {
        D = multiplier[k]*N;
        Po = Pprev = P = sqrtl(D);
        Qprev = 1;
        Q = D - Po*Po;
        L = 2 * sqrtl( 2*s );
        B = 3 * L;
        for (i = 2 ; i < B ; i++) {
            b = (uint64_t)((Po + P)/Q);
            P = b*Q - P;
            q = Q;
            Q = Qprev + b*(Pprev - P);
            r = (uint64_t)(sqrtl(Q)+0.5);
            if (!(i & 1) && r*r == Q) break;
            Qprev = q;
            Pprev = P;
        };
        if (i >= B) continue;
        b = (uint64_t)((Po - P)/r);
        Pprev = P = b*r + P;
        Qprev = r;
        Q = (D - Pprev*Pprev)/Qprev;
        i = 0;
        do {
            b = (uint64_t)((Po + P)/Q);
            Pprev = P;
            P = b*Q - P;
            q = Q;
            Q = Qprev + b*(Pprev - P);
            Qprev = q;
            i++;
        } while (P != Pprev);
        r = gcd(N, Qprev);
        if (r != 1 && r != N) return r;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is this a bug of the given implementation on that page? Can this algorithm fail to find factor for some numbers?

Comment: The description of the algorithm on the linked page is stating very clear that the algorithm does not guarantee factorization of all of the numbers.

Comment: Post your `uint64_t gcd(uint64_t, uint64_t)` implementation. and a  [mcve] is needed to reproduce your "testing that function and noticed that the function is failing to find a factor of 27."

Comment: I am using the builtin gcd function of C++ STL. And I replaced uint64_t with long long int type. Everything else is the same as the given code.

Comment: `long long int` is not the same as `uint64_t` in terms of signedness at the very least.

Comment: But I have also tried using unsigned long long int type. It still fails for 27.

Comment: It is obligatory for almost all factorization algorithms to check for if the number `N` can be expressed as `n^k` with `{n,k}` in **N**. so use a quick nth-root test (e.g.: with Newton for these small numbers) for all `p <= log_2(N)` with `p` prime to save some work. A small sieve might come handy here. You also have to check for `N` being prime, the deterministic form of the Rabin-Miller test will do for 64 bit small integers.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm in the Wikipedia page doesn't check if the denominators of any of the integer divisions are equal to zero.

I tested a [slightly modified version of it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qW82W0fT9kipd7sB) (I also used C++, which is probably what the OP actually used, as they mention the use of "gcd function of C++ STL" in the comments) for the first 32768 values of N, obtaining:

```
N:      3  Q == 0 in the first division
N:      5  Q == 0 in the first division
N:      7  Q == 0 in the first division
N:     11  Q == 0 in the first division
N:     27  Q == 0 in the first division
N:    363  Q == 0 in the first division
N:    867  Q == 0 in the first division
N:   1445  Q == 0 in the first division
N:   5043  Q == 0 in the first division
N:   6845  Q == 0 in the first division
N:   7803  Q == 0 in the first division
N:  10443  Q == 0 in the first division
N:  11163  Q == 0 in the first division
N:  13467  Q == 0 in the first division
N:  14283  Q == 0 in the first division
N:  18491  Q == 0 in the first division
N:  18723  Q == 0 in the first division
N:  23763  Q == 0 in the first division
N:  30603  Q == 0 in the first division
N:  31827  Q == 0 in the first division
```

You'll notice that the first cases are prime numbers and are also present in the `multipliers` array.

Before the inner loop where the first division is performed, the variable `Q` is calculated essentially as

```
D = multiplier[k]*N;
Po = sqrtl(D);
Q = D - Po*Po;
```

So, `Q` is zero, when `D` is a perfect square. You can take care of these corner cases adding a few lines of [code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DlvpGrgwcJZZ28BK):

```
const uint64_t multiplier[] = {
    1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 3*5, 3*7, 3*11, 5*7, 5*11, 7*11, 3*5*7,
    3*5*11, 3*7*11, 5*7*11, 3*5*7*11
};
const uint64_t results[] = {
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3
};
    // ... inside the k loop
    if ( multiplier[k] == N )   
        return results[k];
    // ... calculate Q as before
    if (Q == 0) 
        return std::gcd(multiplier[k], N);
    // ... rest of the loop
```

Comment: Is there any way to handle this so that the code can find factors for these numbers (except primes)?

Comment: @SadmanRizwan I won't pretend to fully understand the theory behind this algorithm, I can only guess that in those cases you can consider it to fail and fallback to another factorization method.

Comment: As far as I know, this algorithm should find a factor for any number except primes. Maybe I need to change a few logics in that code. Thanks for your help anyway.